# Supabase returns error "JWSError JWSInvalidSignature"?

Tags: jwt, supabase

I've got a custom Node GraphQL backend and a Vue3 frontend, both of which implement Supabase. The frontend passes the bearer token to the backend, which simply validates the token and processes the transaction with Supabase. Both point to a local instance of Supabase as well, which I just recently got up and running. It's been about a year and a half since I last worked on this project, and have been working to get it all up to date.
I'm working on a simple currentUser query at the moment, but am running in to an odd issue. Here is the code:

```js
import { userError } from '@/helpers/errors';
import supabase from '@/lib/supabase';
import { CurrentUserPayload } from '@/generated/types';
import { Context } from '@/context';

const me = async (_parent: any, _params: any, context: Context): Promise<MePayload> => {
  try {
    const { data: sessionUser, error: sessionError } = await supabase.auth.getUser(context.token.replace('Bearer ', ''));
    console.log({ sessionUser });
    console.log({ sessionError });

    if (!sessionUser.user || sessionError) {
      return {
        ...userError({ message: 'Must be logged in', path: 'me resolver' }),
      };
    }

    const userId = sessionUser.user?.id;
    const { data: user, error: error } = await supabase
      .from('users')
      .select('*, notifications(*)')
      .eq('id', userId)
      .single();

    console.log({ user });
    console.log({ error });

    if (!user || error) {
      return {
        ...userError({ message: 'Unable to fetch currentUser', path: 'me resolver' }),
      };
    }

    return {
      user,
      errors: null,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      ...userError({ message: 'Error running me resolver', path: 'me resolver' }),
      notifications: [],
      onboardingSteps: [],
    };
  }

};

export default me;
```

The first set of console logs that print the data and error from auth.getUser() return no errors and the correct data. The next request however that selects a user from the database returns a null user and the error:

```
  error: {
    code: 'PGRST301',
    details: null,
    hint: null,
    message: 'JWSError JWSInvalidSignature'
  }
```

I've verified that the JWT secret and public supabase keys are correct (and they would have to be to even get past the `auth.getUser()` function). Has anybody run into something like this, or have an inkling as to what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful for anyone else, I discovered the issue. When running the project in a local environment, I believe the supabase keys are different. Either when running `supabase start` or `supabase status`, you can check out the different `anon_key`, which I plugged into my .env file and now appears to work!